# Migrating windows authentication and abp.io IdentityUser

Tags: angular, authentication, abp, abp.io

I am implementing an Application using ABP.IO framework. I want to have Windows authentication and abp.io identity user Authentication.
I mean that if current Windows user has a group that already defined in abp groups application must create token just like when user enter username and password and if ther is no mapped group redirect user too login page.
i am using angular for UI